# React.JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined - (inside setState)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement, state, setstate

Hello everyone,  
In my ReactJS website I get this error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined` 

 `HTMLInputElement.anonymous ` why ?

I did `console.log(this.state.number)` and number has a value in it.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mobileNum: '',
      number: '',
    };
  }  

  somefunction=()=>{ // Is called with onKeyDown - I checked it does.
    this.setState({ number: document.getElementById('mySubmit').value });

  
  enterPressed = () => {
    const submit = document.getElementById('mySubmit');
    submit.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.setState({ mobileNum: this.state.number }); // Here is the error line !
      }
    });
  };
```

If I use `setState` with `if` condition in another function it will do error - `setState is not a function`

 `this.setState({ mobileNum: this.state.number })` is working also in a different fuction I made, but in `enterPressed()` isn't.

Thanks for the helpers :)

Comment: Where you use enterPressed ?

Comment: @Viet inside the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a fat arrow function

```
enterPressed = () => {
    const submit = document.getElementById('mySubmit');
    submit.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.setState({
                mobileNum: this.state.number
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Murat it just worked, solved this issue. Can you explain me now how it worked ? And why my previous self-invoking function didnt worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You never call `someFunction()` which is supposed to assign a number value to `this.state.number`. When you try to assign `this.state.number` to `mobileNum`, the value is still `undefined`.

Comment: Hi @Casper `someFunction()` is being called each time a key is pressed inside the input field.

Comment: @ExtraSun did you ever figure out why the fat arrow function solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HTML selectors in this function, you can add two-way binding:

```
 enterPressed = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let password = e.target.value();
    this.setState({ ...this.state, mobileNum: password});
  };
```